# Multiple value Filter in ui5

Tags: sapui5

I want to run a filter 2 times for 2 different values. The below filter runs fine and searches if the material M exists in the plant A. What I want to search is material M exists in Plant A and Plant B. So I want to run the below filter 2 times for Plant A search if the material is present then run for plant B. If both the places it exists then call the success function. Whats the best way to do it?
(Plant is like the key)

Controller.js

```
var sServiceURL = self.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app").dataSources["ABC"].uri;
            var OdataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceURL);
            var sPath = "/materialSet";
        var filters = [];

                filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter([
                new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantA),
                new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantB)
            ], true));


            filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Material", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, materialNo));
            filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("type", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, orderType));

            OdataModel.read(sPath, {
                filters: filters,
                success: self.sucess.bind(self),
                error: function(oError) {
                    self.error(oError);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple filters on the same field in this manner:

```
new Filter([
     new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantA),
     new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantB)
], false);
```

This results in a call like:

> and ( plant = 1 or plant = 2 )

If your intention is to check if a part is available in *both* plants, turn it the last parameter into a `true` or leave it blank:

```
new Filter([
     new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantA),
     new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plantB)
], true);
```

> and (plant = 1 and plant = 2)

So, incorporate this as a replacement for `filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, self.plant));`.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my code. (pasted above). But now I am getting one error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. Like you mentioned I want to achieve if a material exists in both plants. Moreso, want to check the combination as below:

something like (PlantA && MatA && Order)  &&  ( PlantB && Mat A && Order). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `self.plantB` is probably undefined, which might cause the first problem. As for the other issue, you get brackets in a query by using the `new Filter` logic as stated above

Comment: Jorg - I have edited the code again and replaced the line exactly. Except I also added filters.push before it. I check in debug all values are there.  Earlier it was reaching success fn call and then giving error in console. Now it is going to error fn and saying pass filter values. But in debug all values are there. Any ideas?

Comment: If it reaches the error function, your odata service returned an error. Your back end might not be catering for the filters you're passing in

Comment: is there a way to call read twice, tried by setting flag in success of 1st read. But it goes to 1 then 2. 
 OdataModel.read(sPath, {
      filters: filters1,
      success: function(oData, response) {
     resolve(oData);  comes here ->1, 2
       success = true;    (2)
      },
      error: function(oError) {
       reject(oError);
        success = false;     
      }
     });

    }
    if (success) {    (1)
     OdataModel.read(sPath, {
      filters: filters,
      success: self.fn.bind(self),
      error: function(oError) {
       self.fn1(oError);
      }
     });

Comment: You should be able to do call number 2 in the success function of call number 1